# Why I get an undefined object when I use chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState?

Tags: bluetooth, google-chrome-app

I'm using Google Chrome 33.0.1729.3 dev on Linux (elementary os 0.2 based on Ubuntu 12.04)

I create a Chrome App and configured the manifest.json to grant bluetooth permissions:

```
{
  "name": "App Name",
  "description": "App Desc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["bluetooth"],
  "icons": { "16": "app-icon-16.png", "128": "app-icon-128.png" }
}
```

when I trigger this script on the app

```
chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState( function( result ) {
  console.log( result );
});
```

The result is an undefined

According to the documentation of Google Chrome Apps the method returns an AdapterState object to the callback.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState( function( result ) {
  if (result) {
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
  }
});
```

Many of the chrome.* APIs use chrome.runtime.lastError to communicate errors to you. Even though it's not documented at http://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth.html, it might work in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I get this: Object {message: "This operation is not supported on your platform"} I have to wait :):

Comment: Aha! I would think (though I'm not sure) that once this API is available on stable channel, you should expect it to work on any platform that is Bluetooth-capable.