# Connecting to an iOS device using the chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app

I have been trying to connect an iPhone 5 to OSX Chrome (Version 38.0.2096.0 dev) over BLE using chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API.

I'm using [BLE Utility](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ble-utility/id606210918?mt=8) on my iphone to simulate battery service. I can discover the service  and connect to it using other phones or [OSX utility](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id639944780?mt=12), but I'm having problems doing so with chrome. I can see my device listed, but no services discovered and when I try to connect to the device, connection fails with the following message:

> Operation failed

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "BLE Test",
  "description": "Chrome BLE Test",
  "version": "1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "bluetooth": {
    "low_energy": true,
    "uuids": ["180f"]
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chrome BLE Test</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```js
function main() {
  var onGetServicesCallback = function(services) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Services:', services.length);

    if (!services) {
      console.log('No services');
      return;
    }

    services.forEach(function(service) {
      console.log(service);
    });
  }

  chrome.bluetooth.getDevices(function(devices) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Found devices:', devices.length);

    if (devices) {
      devices.forEach(function(device) {
        console.log('Device name:', device.name);
        chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.getServices(device.address, onGetServicesCallback);

        chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.connect(device.address, function() {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log('Connection failed:', chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
          }
          console.log('Connected!');
        });
      });
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BLE implementation for the Mac is not complete yet as far as I know. A good place to follow the development of the API is on the Chrome issue tracker. [This is a link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364359) to the issue related to the Mac one specifically. To see all the bluetooth changes, just search for bluetooth under open issues.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a working implementation for any platform? I found this example https://github.com/armansito/ble-battery-service-demo posted by one of the Chrome developers, so I'm assuiming it should be working with some OS? I have tried ubuntu with no luck, similar issue to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448699/why-i-get-an-undefined-object-when-i-use-chrome-bluetooth-getadapterstate

Comment: I think they have Chromium OS working? I believe Linux was last on their list, but they had tickets open for different OS versions. Here are some more tickets that I follow: Windows: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388016 General Gatt: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=351223 Chrome OS: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360268

Comment: Now, half a year later. Where can I find out what the status of the BLE implemetation is? The API docs are public, but the sample apps still don't work.

Comment: The most recent issue I have seen updated for this is here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449682