# Chrome : Bluetooth L2CAP protocal is not supported

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app, l2cap

I want to connect my bluetooth remote control using chrome application, but i get folowwing error "Bluetooth L2CAP protocal is not supported"
I want to connect my bluetooth remote or mobile with chrome app without using windows support.
Pls help
regards

```js
var main = (function() {
  // GATT Device Information Service UUIDs
  var DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID      = '0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
  var MANUFACTURER_NAME_STRING_UUID = '00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
  var SERIAL_NUMBER_STRING_UUID     = '00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
  var HARDWARE_REVISION_STRING_UUID = '00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
  var FIRMWARE_REVISION_STRING_UUID = '00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
  var SOFTWARE_REVISION_STRING_UUID = '00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
  var PNP_ID_UUID                   = '00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';

  function DeviceInfoDemo() {
    // A mapping from device addresses to device names for found devices that
    // expose a Battery service.
    this.deviceMap_ = {};

    // The currently selected service and its characteristics.
    this.service_ = null;
    this.chrcMap_ = {};
    this.discovering_ = false;
  }

  /**
   * Sets up the UI for the given service.
   */
  DeviceInfoDemo.prototype.selectService = function(service) {
    // Hide or show the appropriate elements based on whether or not
    // |serviceId| is undefined.
    UI.getInstance().resetState(!service);

    this.service_ = service;
    this.chrcMap_ = {};

    if (!service) {
      console.log('No service selected.');
      return;
    }

    console.log('GATT service selected: ' + service.instanceId);

    // Get the characteristics of the selected service.
    var self = this;
    chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.getCharacteristics(service.instanceId,
                                                 function (chrcs) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
      }

      // Make sure that the same service is still selected.
      if (service.instanceId != self.service_.instanceId)
        return;

      if (chrcs.length == 0) {
        console.log('Service has no characteristics: ' + service.instanceId);
        return;
      }

      chrcs.forEach(function (chrc) {
        var fieldId;
        var valueDisplayFunction = UI.getInstance().setStringValue;

        if (chrc.uuid == MANUFACTURER_NAME_STRING_UUID) {
          console.log('Setting Manufacturer Name String Characteristic: ' +
                      chrc.instanceId);
          fieldId = 'manufacturer-name-string';
        } else if (chrc.uuid == SERIAL_NUMBER_STRING_UUID) {
          console.log('Setting Serial Number String Characteristic: ' +
                      chrc.instanceId);
          fieldId = 'serial-number-string';
        } else if (chrc.uuid == HARDWARE_REVISION_STRING_UUID) {
          console.log('Setting Hardware Revision String Characteristic: ' +
                      chrc.instanceId);
          fieldId = 'hardware-revision-string';
        } else if (chrc.uuid == FIRMWARE_REVISION_STRING_UUID) {
          console.log('Setting Firmware Revision String Characteristic: ' +
                      chrc.instanceId);
          fieldId = 'firmware-revision-string';
        } else if (chrc.uuid == SOFTWARE_REVISION_STRING_UUID) {
          console.log('Setting Software Revision String Characteristic: ' +
                      chrc.instanceId);
          fieldId = 'software-revision-string';
        } else if (chrc.uuid == PNP_ID_UUID) {
          console.log('Setting PnP ID Characteristic: ' + chrc.instanceId);
          fieldId = 'pnp-id';
          valueDisplayFunction = UI.getInstance().setPnpIdValue;
        }

        if (fieldId === undefined) {
          console.log('Ignoring characteristic "' + chrc.instanceId +
                      '" with UUID ' + chrc.uuid);
          return;
        }

        self.chrcMap_[fieldId] = chrc;

        // Read the value of the characteristic and store it.
        chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.readCharacteristicValue(chrc.instanceId,
                                                          function (readChrc) {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
          }

          // Make sure that the same characteristic is still selected.
          if (!self.chrcMap_.hasOwnProperty(fieldId) ||
              self.chrcMap_[fieldId].instanceId != readChrc.instanceId)
            return;

          self.chrcMap_[fieldId] = readChrc;
          valueDisplayFunction(fieldId, readChrc.value);
        });
      });
    });
  };

  DeviceInfoDemo.prototype.updateDiscoveryToggleState = function(discovering) {
    if (this.discovering_ !== discovering) {
      this.discovering_ = discovering;
      UI.getInstance().setDiscoveryToggleState(this.discovering_);
    }
  };

  DeviceInfoDemo.prototype.init = function() {
    // Set up the UI to look like no device was initially selected.
    this.selectService(null);

    // Store the |this| to be used by API callbacks below.
    var self = this;

    // Request information about the local Bluetooth adapter to be displayed in
    // the UI.
    var updateAdapterState = function(adapterState) {
      UI.getInstance().setAdapterState(adapterState.address, adapterState.name);
      self.updateDiscoveryToggleState(adapterState.discovering);
    };

    chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState(function (adapterState) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);

      self.updateDiscoveryToggleState(adapterState.discovering);
      updateAdapterState(adapterState);
    });

    chrome.bluetooth.onAdapterStateChanged.addListener(updateAdapterState);

    // Helper functions used below.
    var isKnownDevice = function(deviceAddress) {
      return self.deviceMap_.hasOwnProperty(deviceAddress);
    };

    var storeDevice = function(deviceAddress, device) {
      var resetUI = false;
      if (device == null) {
        delete self.deviceMap_[deviceAddress];
        resetUI = true;
      } else {
        self.deviceMap_[deviceAddress] =
            (device.name ? device.name : device.address);
      }

      // Update the selector UI with the new device list.
      UI.getInstance().updateDeviceSelector(self.deviceMap_, resetUI);
    };

    // Initialize the device map.
 chrome.bluetooth.getDevices(function(devices) {
 for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    //console.log(devices[i].address);
 //console.log(devices[i].name);
 }
 
//-------------------------------------------------
var device_names = {};
var updateDeviceName = function(device) {
  device_names[device.address] = device.name;
 if(device.name == 'Advanced Touch REMOTE')
 {
  console.log(device.address);
  var uuid = '1124';
  var onConnectedCallback = function() {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
   console.log("Connection failed: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
   console.log("Socket: " + JSON.stringify(device));
  } else {
   console.log('Connected to Remote');
   console.log("Socket: " + JSON.stringify(device));
}

};
 chrome.bluetoothSocket.create(function(createInfo) {
 chrome.bluetoothSocket.connect(createInfo.socketId,
    device.address, uuid, onConnectedCallback);
}); 
 }

 console.log(device.address);
 console.log(device.name);
 storeDevice(device.address, device);
};
var removeDeviceName = function(device) {
  delete device_names[device.address];
}

// Add listeners to receive newly found devices and updates
// to the previously known devices.
chrome.bluetooth.onDeviceAdded.addListener(updateDeviceName);
chrome.bluetooth.onDeviceChanged.addListener(updateDeviceName);
chrome.bluetooth.onDeviceRemoved.addListener(removeDeviceName);

// With the listeners in place, get the list of devices found in
// previous discovery sessions, or any currently active ones,
// along with paired devices.
chrome.bluetooth.getDevices(function(devices) {
  for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    updateDeviceName(devices[i]);
  }
});


// Now begin the discovery process.
chrome.bluetooth.startDiscovery(function() {
  // Stop discovery after 30 seconds.
  setTimeout(function() {
    chrome.bluetooth.stopDiscovery(function() {});
  }, 25000);
});
//-------------------------------------------------
});

  };

  return {
    DeviceInfoDemo: DeviceInfoDemo
  };
})();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var demo = new main.DeviceInfoDemo();
  demo.init();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
  padding: 10px 15px 5px 15px;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #858585;
}

#header img {
  width: 50px;
}

#header h1 {
  font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Light', Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#adapter-status {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#adapter-address {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: inherit;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#device-selection-div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#device-selector {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  color: #454545;
  font-style: italic;
}

#discovery-toggle-button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  color: #454545;
  font-style: italic;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

#no-devices-error {
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

#info-div {
  height: 245px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  color: #333;
}

.device-info-field {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.device-info-field span {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bluetooth LE Device Information Service Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="ui.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img src="bluetooth.png" alt="bluetooth icon">
    <h1>BLE Device Information Service</h1>
    <div id="adapter-status">
      <ul>
        <li><span id="adapter-name"></span></li>
        <li><span id="adapter-address"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="device-selection-div">
      Select device with Device Information Service:
      <select id="device-selector">
        <option id="placeholder" value="" disabled selected>
          No connected devices
        </option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" id="discovery-toggle-button">
        start discovery
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="no-devices-error">
    No device with "Device Information Service" selected.
  </div>
  <div id="info-div">
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Manufacturer Name: <span id="manufacturer-name-string">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Serial Number: <span id="serial-number-string">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Hardware Revision: <span id="hardware-revision-string">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Firmware Revision: <span id="firmware-revision-string">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Software Revision: <span id="software-revision-string">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Vendor ID Source: <span id="vendor-id-source">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Vendor ID: <span id="vendor-id">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Product ID: <span id="product-id">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device-info-field">
      Product Version: <span id="product-version">-</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

regards

Answer (score 2):

As of early 2015, the chrome.bluetoothLowenergy Chrome App API is **only implemented on Chrome OS**. The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetoothLowEnergy) does not mention this anywhere, but it is an important note! You can search for bluetoothLowEnergy on crbug.com to find other people who have been confused because the documentation does not mention this fact. See also question [Connecting to an iOS device using the chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880860/connecting-to-an-ios-device-using-the-chrome-bluetoothlowenergy-api).

To see progress of implementation for Chrome on desktop, star one of these issues: [364359: Implement GATT API on OS X](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364359) and [388016: Implement the chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API on Windows](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388016). I don’t think there is any current plan to support it on desktop Linux (even though they already did implement it on ChromeOS).

@Xan, I have created [Issue 460741: chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API documentation does not list supported platforms](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460741) to suggest that the API documentation be updated.

Comment: Please create a bug specifically to update documentation to reflect that, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

From all I can tell, this is all implemented and documented now (well, it's been a while).

Docs:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/app_bluetooth/

Feature Status: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5264933985976320