# chrome.bluetooth.getDevices is not discovering a BLE device

Tags: javascript, macos, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

Running the [heart-rate-sensor example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/bluetooth-samples/heart-rate-sensor), I am unable to detect a BLE device (known-good heart-rate sensor evaluation kit) in the resulting callback after a `chrome.bluetooth.getDevices` call.

Even If I attempt to periodically re-call `getDevices` every 5s:

```
setInterval(chrome.bluetooth.getDevices, 5000, onDeviceSearchCompleted);
```

and toy with the power on the ble device, I only see audio devices I previously connected to in my `onDeviceSearchCompleted` callback.

The device is clearly advertising and discoverable as I can see it through this [mac app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id639944780?mt=12).

Comment: Considering you [know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140933/is-the-chrome-bluetoothlowenergy-api-ready-for-mac-or-windows-or-linux) about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880860/connecting-to-an-ios-device-using-the-chrome-bluetoothlowenergy-api why are you surprised? It's still not implemented on OS X.

Comment: That was a while ago and I'm looking for a way to understand the state of the API.  There's nothing the docs.  Does it work on Windows or Ubuntu?  It's OK if it doesn't.  I just need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLE Chrome API not yet implemented on [OSX](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364359&q=osx%20bluetooth&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) or [Windows](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388016). Keep waiting. Too bad the [Chrome Bluetooth API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth) has no mention of supported OS's. It got my hopes up too.

Comment: Do you have a source on that? I can confirm that I can pick up devices on my Linux machine but not my Windows, but they're both using different Bluetooth adapters too.

Comment: @NessDan, my source is running the demo's on various devices when I wrote the post. If it's working for you, awesome. :)

Comment: Ah, the scientific method! Well thank you for this still, would have easily spent a few more days trying to figure out why Chrome Windows wasn't picking up BLE!